# selenium python how to close popu tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

if I click any of menu on this [page](https://www.doordash.com/store/stark%27s-hot-chicken-los-angeles-1064390/?cursor=eyJzdG9yZV92ZXJ0aWNhbF9pZCI6bnVsbCwic2VhcmNoX2l0ZW1fY2Fyb3VzZWxfY3Vyc29yIjp7InF1ZXJ5IjoiY2hpY2tlbiIsIml0ZW1faWRzIjpbXSwic2VhcmNoX3Rlcm0iOiJjaGlja2VuIiwidmVydGljYWxfaWQiOm51bGwsInZlcnRpY2FsX25hbWUiOiIifSwiaXNfc2libGluZyI6ZmFsc2V9&pickup=false) it will show menu info. But how I can close the popup ? see the screenshot
[image]

I tied those code but didn't work.
`driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.styles__ActionWrapper-sc-v9lptc-1 svg')` , `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='styles__ActionWrapper-sc-v9lptc-1 eekxlt']")`

Comment: Can you share with us a dummy address to get around the **Enter Your Delivery Address** popup, with current location (outside US) the popup won't allow to click on any menu within.

Comment: If you are outside from US then you need to use VPN for access the site. You don't need to provide any dummy address. just click the link and  it will take you the page

Comment: Incase you update the question with the text based HTML of the element, let me know, I can give it a go...

Comment: @undetectedSelenium the pop-up asking for `Your Delivery Address` has exactly the same element :)

Answer (score 0):

As I see

```py
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.styles__ActionWrapper-sc-v9lptc-1 button')
```

Or

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='styles__ActionWrapper-sc-v9lptc-1 eekxlt']/button")
```

Should work, but you have to add a delay to make these elements fully loaded before clicking them.
The best way is to use `visibility_of_element_located` expected condition explicit wait.
Like this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".styles__ActionWrapper-sc-v9lptc-1 button"))).click()
```

Comment: I tried after fully page load but didn't work

Comment: What error do you see?

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='styles__ActionWrapper'] button[class^='styles__StyledButtonRoot']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@class, 'styles__ActionWrapper')]//button[starts-with(@class, 'styles__StyledButtonRoot')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: just to understand: how your answer actually differs from my? Especially after the author wrote he is trying to click after the page is fully loaded i.e. no need to add any waits.

Comment: @Prophet There are several differences and the major one being, you are considering the all the _`classnames`_ where some of them are dynamically generated, where as I have considered the static ones. Second and most important, while answering our focus shouldn't only cover OP's specific usecase. Rather answers should be helpful to the future visitors as well. Better not to assume all the future visitor will notice the clause _trying to click after the page is fully loaded_ but take care of the situation.

Comment: Well, let's see if this answer will work better for the author.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the other two answers are fine (I didn't test them, but I suppose their authors did) but here is my take on the whole issue, difference being the way I select the item as seen from a US connection:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label = 'Close Combo #1']"))).click()
```

This assumes you selected `Combo #1` from the menu. You can change that locator dynamically, depending on the menu selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()

options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",

 Arrays.asList("disable-popup-blocking"))
```

Try this code